# get listview value when click item in other page.xaml

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

> i have the class with listview, the listview is getting values from sqlite

```
public Lista()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        carregaLista();
    }


    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Home));
    }


    public async void carregaLista()
    {

        var local = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "hinos.sqlite");
        SQLiteAsyncConnection con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(local, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);

        listaHinos.ItemsSource = await con.Table<hinos>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public void listaHinos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail),listaHinos.ItemsSource); // passing listview to hinoDetail Class
    }
```

> I am passing the list view to hinoDetail Class below

```
 public hinoDetail()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        // List<hinos> result = e.Parameter as List<hinos>;
        hinos result = (e.Parameter as List<hinos>).FirstOrDefault(); // get first line only
        nomeHinoDetail.Text = result.numHino + " " + result.nomeHino;
        textBlock.Text = result.letraHino;
    }

    private void AppBarButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame.Navigate(typeof(Lista));
    }
```

> The hinoDetail Class is getting only the first value from listview because ( FirstOrDefault() but i dont know what method i need.) and i would like get the value that i click. (if i click in the 1st -> get the 1st, if i cleck in the 2nd -> get the 2nd value) .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not pass whole list item-source to hinoDetail class. It's (by name) a details class which in any case requires one instance of hino.

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail),listaHinos.SelectedItem);
```

And then in hinoDetail class:

```
hinos result = (e.Parameter as hinos);
```